# Can't find data in php file ,sent by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I create to file `ajax.php` and `jajaxget.php`.

script in ajax.php is-

```
<script>
var data={name:"nikhil"};
$.ajax({type:"post",url:"jajaxget.php",data: {name:"nikhil"},success:function(r,s){alert(s);alert(r);}});
</script>
```

and jajaxget.php is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo $_POST["name"];
?>
```

ajax.php works fine and in alert i can see the data which i send. I get a success alert and this ALERT

[image: alert]

But when i open the get.php file in browser there is nothing . "nikhil" should show on the page.  but the page is blank . why data is not recived by `jajaxget.php` file.  It may be very foolish question .but please help

Comment: In Url, It's `jajaxget.php` and you are showing us `get.php`.

Comment: it is just an example. i am using different files name in my project. there is already a file with name get.php, so i use jajaxget.php.

Comment: Please don't show any example here. We can't assume your problem by seeing examples. We need real code.

Comment: sorry i made changes in question

Comment: Answer is well explained by @J. C. Rocamonde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should *not* show on the page when you open it on the browser because you are not passing any POST data when you do so. Your code is working as expected. I think your problem is you do not really get to understand how GET/POST works.

In the post environment variable the post data sent on request is stored. It is not stored forever nor as  kind of a cookie. When you make another request, the variable will have different data according with the headers of the request.

So when you are using AJAX and send post data to your file, the return shows the "name" value you've passed because you've sent it on the request headers. However, when you request the page on a browser and you are not passing any POST data, that won't be shown, because nothing you've sent.

If you want your server to store that data, you may use databases or cookies for that.

For more information read some webpages online like http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp. And please try to understand a bit how the web works before filing it of low quality questions.

If you still have doubts, please ask me.

Comment: i using post method here. please can u please explain little more.

Comment: You cannot use POST request by just opening a page in a browser. You have to submit a form or do an AJAX request with the parameter set in order to see it like output.

Comment: @ErikČerpnjak are you replying me or explaining him/her?

Comment: okkk. u mean it never changes the data in original file. it get the result assuming that what data that file return if we send a particular data

Comment: @user6733315 sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. Are you making me a question? Could you please re-write it so that I understand it a bit better?

Comment: I mean, if we send data using ajax, it never really sends data to original file, original  file will remain same.am i right?

Comment: Yes, @user6733315 . Hypertext preprocessing consists basically on an adaptation of programming languages, by which the file is not _modified_, but executed. When you request a file, this will be preprocessed by PHP and the return will be the output of that execution. When you use the post variable to print out some data, it will take the data from post request each time the file is run, so in case you load it in the browser, as I said, since your POST data is none, it will render nothing.

Comment: @user6733315 and please consider accepting my answer if it was helpful for you and you think I solved your problem.